# Don't see Debugger menu in ILSpy

Tags: c#

I am using  ILSpy to try to debug a running application.  I saw this in an earlier Stackoverflow question [a link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10184935/how-to-use-ilspy-debug-a-dll)! which had a picture of a Debugger menu.  When I load ILSpy the only menus I see are File, View, and Help.  How can I see the Debugger menu?

Comment: They were talking about the preview version of ILSpy.  Afaik the feature was removed in the release version, too buggy probably.  Reflector has it.

Comment: I downloaded Reflector, but I don't see a Debugger menu.  The only menus are File Edit View Tools Help.  I can load a DLL and see all the functions, but what I want to do is see what function call get called when I choose a menu command from the running program (this is a 3rd party application).

Answer (score 0):

Debugger is available for preview version of ILSpy, which they later removed. Don't know the reason behind it.

Alternatively you can use Reflector by RedGate or dotPeek by JetBeans or JustDecompile by Telerik

Answer (score 0):

Found the following explanation on github:

> ILSpy 2.x used to have an experimental debugger; but it was too much
> work to maintain a debugger engine in addition to the decompiler
> engine, so we dropped that approach

https://github.com/icsharpcode/ILSpy/issues/1427#issuecomment-464769024